# Faulty connection JBoss servers in the cluster

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, cluster-computing

I'm trying to connect two servers (jboss 6 eap in a cluster). In the domain controller, I see two servers, then deplying test application. Unfortunately, the test was negative, the session is different. What could be the problem?

domain.xml

```
<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.7">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>
        ...
        ...
    </extensions>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.net.preferIPv4Stack" value="true"/>
    </system-properties>

    <management>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profiles>
        <profile name="full-ha">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">
                <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                    <level name="INFO"/>
                    ...
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:cmp:1.1"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.2">

                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.2">
                <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
                <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
                <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.5">
                <session-bean>
                    <stateless>
                        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                    </stateless>
                    <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" clustered-cache-ref="clustered"/>
                    <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
                </session-bean>
                <mdb>
                    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra}"/>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </mdb>
                <pools>
                    <bean-instance-pools>
                        <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                        <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    </bean-instance-pools>
                </pools>
                <caches>
                    <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                    <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
                    <cache name="clustered" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="StatefulTreeCache"/>
                </caches>
                <passivation-stores>
                    <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
                    <cluster-passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb"/>
                </passivation-stores>
                <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                    <data-stores>
                        <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                    </data-stores>
                </timer-service>
                <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
                <thread-pools>
                    <thread-pool name="default">
                        <max-threads count="10"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                    </thread-pool>
                </thread-pools>
                <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
                <default-security-domain value="other"/>
                <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.5">
                <cache-container name="singleton" aliases="cluster ha-partition" default-cache="default">
                    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                    <replicated-cache name="default" mode="SYNC" batching="true">
                        <locking isolation="REPEATABLE_READ"/>
                    </replicated-cache>
                </cache-container>
                <cache-container name="web" aliases="standard-session-cache" default-cache="repl" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan">
                    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                    <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <file-store/>
                    </replicated-cache>
                    <replicated-cache name="sso" mode="SYNC" batching="true"/>
                    <distributed-cache name="dist" l1-lifespan="0" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <file-store/>
                    </distributed-cache>
                </cache-container>
                <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb sfsb-cache" default-cache="repl" module="org.jboss.as.clustering.ejb3.infinispan">
                    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                    <replicated-cache name="repl" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <file-store/>
                    </replicated-cache>
                    <replicated-cache name="remote-connector-client-mappings" mode="SYNC" batching="true"/>
                    <distributed-cache name="dist" l1-lifespan="0" mode="ASYNC" batching="true">
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <file-store/>
                    </distributed-cache>
                </cache-container>
                <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
                    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                    <local-cache name="local-query">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </local-cache>
                    <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC">
                        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                        <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                        <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                    </invalidation-cache>
                    <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC">
                        <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                    </replicated-cache>
                </cache-container>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.4">
                <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
                    <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
                </orb>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxr:1.1">
                <connection-factory jndi-name="java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
                <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
                <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
                <default-workmanager>
                    <short-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </short-running-threads>
                    <long-running-threads>
                        <core-threads count="50"/>
                        <queue-length count="50"/>
                        <max-threads count="50"/>
                        <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                    </long-running-threads>
                </default-workmanager>
                <cached-connection-manager/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="tcp">
                <stack name="tcp">
                    <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                    <protocol type="TCPPING">
                        <property name="initial_hosts">
                            192.168.11.156[7600],192.168.11.157[7600]
                        </property>
                        <property name="port_range">
                            10
                        </property>
                        <property name="timeout">
                            3000
                        </property>
                        <property name="num_initial_members">
                            2
                        </property>
                    </protocol>
                    <protocol type="MERGE2"/>
                    <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                    <protocol type="FD"/>
                    <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK"/>
                    <protocol type="UNICAST2"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                    <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                    <protocol type="UFC"/>
                    <protocol type="MFC"/>
                    <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                    <protocol type="RSVP"/>
                </stack>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
                <expose-resolved-model/>
                <expose-expression-model/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
                <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.2">
                <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                    <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
                </mail-session>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.4">
                <hornetq-server>
                    <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                    <cluster-password>${jboss.messaging.cluster.password:jmspassword}</cluster-password>
                    <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
                    <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                    <connectors>
                        <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                        <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        </netty-connector>
                        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </connectors>

                    <acceptors>
                        <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                        <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                            <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                            <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                        </netty-acceptor>
                        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    </acceptors>

                    <broadcast-groups>
                        <broadcast-group name="bg-group1">
                            <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                            <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
                            <connector-ref>
                                netty
                            </connector-ref>
                        </broadcast-group>
                    </broadcast-groups>

                    <discovery-groups>
                        <discovery-group name="dg-group1">
                            <socket-binding>messaging-group</socket-binding>
                            <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
                        </discovery-group>
                    </discovery-groups>

                    <cluster-connections>
                        <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                            <address>jms</address>
                            <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
                            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group1"/>
                        </cluster-connection>
                    </cluster-connections>

                    <security-settings>
                        <security-setting match="#">
                            <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        </security-setting>
                    </security-settings>

                    <address-settings>
                        <address-setting match="#">
                            <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                            <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                            <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                            <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                            <redistribution-delay>1000</redistribution-delay>
                        </address-setting>
                    </address-settings>

                    <jms-connection-factories>
                        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                            </entries>
                            <ha>true</ha>
                            <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                            <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                            <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                        </connection-factory>
                        <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                            <transaction mode="xa"/>
                            <connectors>
                                <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                            </connectors>
                            <entries>
                                <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                            </entries>
                        </pooled-connection-factory>
                    </jms-connection-factories>

                    <jms-destinations>
                        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                            <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                        </jms-queue>
                        <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                           <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                        </jms-queue>
                    </jms-destinations>
                </hornetq-server>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
                <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
                    <dynamic-load-provider>
                        <load-metric type="busyness"/>
                    </dynamic-load-provider>
                </mod-cluster-config>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.4">
                <remote-naming/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.2">
                <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
                <security-domains>
                    <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                        <authentication>
                            <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                            <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                                <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                            </login-module>
                        </authentication>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                    <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                        <authorization>
                            <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                        </authorization>
                    </security-domain>
                </security-domains>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.5">
                <core-environment>
                    <process-id>
                        <uuid/>
                    </process-id>
                </core-environment>
                <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
                <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
                <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
                <connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                    <alias name="localhost"/>
                    <alias name="example.com"/>
                </virtual-server>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
                <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
                <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
                <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
                <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                    <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                       <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                    </pre-handler-chain>
                </endpoint-config>
                <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
            </subsystem>
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management"/>
        <interface name="public"/>
        <interface name="unsecure"/>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-groups>
        <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
        <socket-binding-group name="ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
            <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
        <socket-binding-group name="full-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
            <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
            <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
        <socket-binding-group name="full-ha-sockets" default-interface="public">
            <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
            <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
            <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
            <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
            <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
            <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
            <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
            <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
            <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
            <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
                <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
            <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-ejb" source-port="0" fixed-source-port="false">
                <remote-destination host="192.168.11.156" port="4447"/>
            </outbound-socket-binding>
        </socket-binding-group>
    </socket-binding-groups>

    <deployments>
        <deployment name="clustertest.ear" runtime-name="clustertest.ear">
            <content sha1="20def250418d325ebf5930aaa8e5007821b866b1"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>

    <server-groups>
        <server-group name="prod-server-group" profile="full-ha">
            <jvm name="default">
                <heap size="1024m" max-size="1024m"/>
                <permgen max-size="256m"/>
            </jvm>
            <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/>
            <deployments>
                <deployment name="clustertest.ear" runtime-name="clustertest.ear"/>
            </deployments>
        </server-group>
    </server-groups>

</domain>
```

[image: Console]

[image: Master]

[image: Slave]

Comment: It is not enough to comment anything.
Issue could be in two areas.

 1 ) Your cluster configuration issue ( Need your domain.xml to verify )
 2 ) Application is not good enough to handle session . ( Need to check your application coding fashion )

Comment: domain.xml added /I removed the profiles of which don't use/